# Export class static method

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is possible I export a class static method on TypeScript to NodeJs? Example:

```
class Help {
    static show() { ... }
}

export = Help.show;
```

It returns it:

```
class.Help.ts(5,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
class Help {
    static show() {  }
}

var show = Help.show;
export = show;
```

The limitation is by design. Stuff after `export =` needs to be an identifier. E.g. the following will not compile either:

```
var foo = {show:()=>null}
export = foo.show;
```

Comment: Awesome! It's better than my own method. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Note you only need ` .apply` if you want to preserve `this` in a function. This is not required for static methods as `this` will not point to *some instance*. `this` preservation is need for member methods and typescript has good ways : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 0):

**I found a good solution for me:**

```
class Help {
    static show() { ... }
}

export function show() { return Help.show.apply(this, arguments); }
```

But I think that is possible exists a native solution. Right?